# Vim:inserting regex matches to beginning of the line

Tags: regex, vim

Recently found out about vim.
I have a list of lines that are of the form

`<title>-<course name>p.<optional space><part number><extra text>.mp4`

I want to get the part name to the front of the file, i.e it should end up like

`p.<part number><title>-<course name><extra text>.mp4`

I know it's pretty simple to do using a programming language, but I wanted to know how I would do this in vim.
Below this line is what I've arrived to, but \1 doesn't seem to append the group.

`:g/\(p\.\s\=[0-9]*\)/s/^/\1`

I'm pretty sure the regex is correct based on what it's highlighting, but just wanted to know how I'm supposed to insert it to the beginning of each line.
example filename below, in case my explanation isn't clear:

`titleofvideo -coursename p.13-44jq6ano5n0.mp4`

I wanna change it to

`p.13-titleofvideo -coursename -44jq6ano5n0.mp4`

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to match both parts and then swap them: `:%s/\v(.*)(p\.\s?\d+)/\2-\1`

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@L3viathan gives the following working command in the comments:

```
%substitute/\v(.*)(p\.\s?\d+)/\2-\1/
```

The reason the OP’s command did not work is because after the `s/^/`, there is no group in the previous regex (which is now `^` and not the `global` pattern).